# custom registrationCode domain class Spring Security UI Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

Holla
i want to customize RegistrationCode domain class without changing the ui plugin but i don't find it in s2ui override.
For precision it to include multi tenant for registrated user by tenant

Answer (score 1):

You do this the same way as you would for any artifact in a plugin - create your application class with the same name and package under `grails-app` and yours will override the one from the plugin.

This works because Grails orders the sources for the classloader(s) with the application's classes before the plugins' classes, so if a class is found from the application it will be loaded and the plugin's corresponding class will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks but i've already tried it. But i got an error on hibernate there to domain with same name make troubles: